# Implementing the summation function to dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Good day.

I intend to implement the summation function shown in the figure below to a data frame in Python:
[image]

I have tried the code below as a simple working example but I am not getting the results intended:

```
D_data = [0.1, 0.22, 0.353, 4.25, 12.5];
max_state=5;
total_numerator_1 = 0
total_numerator_2 = 0
total_denominator = 0
for i, coefficient in enumerate(D_data):
  for j in range(1,max_state):
     total_numerator_2 += j * coefficient**2
     total_numerator_1 += j * coefficient
     total_denominator += I


print('lambda1:', total_numerator_1 / total_denominator)
print('lambda2:', total_numerator_2 / total_numerator_1)
```

For instance, the expected output for lambda1 and lambda2 are :

```
lambda1= ((0.1*1)+(0.22*2)+(0.353*3)+(4.25*4)+(12.5*5))/(0.1+0.22+0.353+4.25+12.5)= 4.655(Approx.)
lambda2= ((0.1^2 X 1)+(0.22^2 X 2)+(0.353^2 X 3)+(4.25^2 X 4)+(12.5^2 X 5))/(0.1+0.22+0.353+4.25+12.5)= 10.530(Approx.)
```

Any timely help suggestions for the solution will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: you will get the same results, because you are dividing l2.sum() with l1.sum()

Comment: What is `d_result['D']`?

Comment: The idea is that suppose d_result['D']=[1,2,3,4,5] then: l1=(1×1)+(2×2)+(3×3)+... and l2= (1×1^2)+(2×2^2)+(3×3^2)+...From ,this simple working example, lambda1 and lamba 2 should be different.

Comment: Are you looking to do these in a pandas dataframe? is `D_data` the data in your dataframe?

Comment: Also your `lambda2` calculation is wrong, it should be 49.014557022326805

Comment: Thank you @PranavHosangadi. Are you certain about the value you quoted I still have 10.530 for lambda2?

Comment: @teddiclax yes, I copied that expression to a python REPL, replaced `^` with `**` and `X` with `*`, and the result I get is 49.014... I am more confident because the calculation in my answer below gives the same result. If you are getting 10.530, then you want a different calculation that is not the one you have shown in your question

Comment: Thank you for your timely response@PranavHosangadi. You were right. My intention was to divide the denominator of "lambda2" by the numerator of "lambda1". Can you take a new look at the code?

Comment: @teddiclax my answer shows how to get both numerators (just don't divide by `total`). Them do whatever you need to do with those numerators

Answer (score 0):

Given a list `D`, it looks like you want to calculate `l1 = (D[0] * 1 + D[1] * 2 + D[2] * 3 + ...) / (D[0] + D[1] + D[2] + ...)`, and `l2 = (D[0]**2 * 1 + D[1]**2 * 2 + D[2]**2 * 3 + ...) / (D[0] + D[1] + D[2] + ...)`

In pure python, you can write these operations as:

```
total = sum(D)
l1 = sum(d * i for i, d in enumerate(D, 1)) / total           # 4.654709292314756
l2 = sum(d**2 * i for i, d in enumerate(D, 1)) / total        # 49.014557022326805
```

If you're using pandas for your dataframes, you can use pandas's `sum` to outsource the calculation to the backend:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

D_df = pd.DataFrame(D, columns=["data"])

multipliers = (np.arange(len(D_df)) + 1).reshape((-1, 1))

total = D_df.sum(axis=0)
lambda1 = (D_df * multipliers).sum(axis=0) / total
lambda2 = (D_df**2 * multipliers).sum(axis=0) / total
```

`multipliers` is simply a column-vector (array of shape `(*, 1)`) containing the numbers `[1, 2, 3, ..., len(D_df)]`

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to print lambda1 instead of lambda2

Comment: Thank you for the swift response @Abinash. The results obtained for lambda1 and lambda2 were unexpectedly equal in terms of value. That was my challenge.